# django: return string from view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I know this is a simple question, sorry.  I just want to return a simple string, no templates.

I have my view:

```
def myview(request):
    return "return this string"
```

I don't remember the command.  Thanks

Answer (score 118, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that
>   takes a Web request and returns a Web response.
>
> Each view function is responsible for returning an HttpResponse
>   object.

In other words, your view should return a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) instance:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponse("return this string")
```

Answer (score 13):

If you create a chat-bot or need this response on post request for confirmation - you should add decorator, otherwise Django block post requests.
More info you can find here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/

Also in my case I had to add content_type="text/plain".

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.http import HttpResponse
@csrf_exempt
def Index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World", content_type="text/plain")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't send directly a string, but you can send a JSON object:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def myview(request):
    return JsonResponse({'mystring':"return this string"})
```

Then process that. With Javascript for example if the page was requested by AJAX:

```
$.ajax({url: '/myview/',    type: 'GET',
                            data: data,
                            success: function(data){ 
                                console.log(data.mystring);
                                ...
                                 }
                            })
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Answer (score 4):

we use HttpResponse to render the Data

HttpResponse to render the Text

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def Index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

HttpResponse to render the HTML

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
    def Index(request):
        text = """<h1>Hello World</h1>"""
        return HttpResponse(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/',views.aboutview),
    path('',views.homeview),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def aboutview(request):
  return HttpResponse("<h1>about page</h1>")

def homeview(request):
  return HttpResponse("<h1>home page</h1>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to clear the air should someone bump to this in the feature, like wanting to pass any sort of string.
I hard to do the following, starting with the view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse        
def myview(request):
    text = """<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>"""
    return HttpResponse(text)
```

Then urls, btw the endpoint here "submit/myview" can be anything

```
 path('submit/myview', views.myview, name='myview'),

the ajax side of things on the template where you want to render this 

 
<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "myview");
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According Django documentation Django uses request and response objects to pass state through the system.

When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that contains metadata about the request. Then Django loads the appropriate view, passing the HttpRequest as the first argument to the view function. Each view is responsible for returning an HttpResponse object.Do as follows

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def myview(request):
    text="return this string"
    return HttpResponse(text)
```