# Unable to start DJango server in codesandbox online editor

Tags: python, django, codesandbox

I am unable to start DJango server in the codesandbox online editor.

I have created a minimal app (see code below) but I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://jhkvsl-8000.csb.app/

Django Version: 4.2.1
Python Version: 3.11.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'apis']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Code Written inside the project

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'apis',
]
```

apis/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.apis, name="home"),
]
```

apis/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


def apis(request):
    return "Working fine"
```

complete project link -> https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/django-project-api-jhkvsl

I am just trying to know weather it is possible to code django application in codesandbox or not.

Comment: You cannot return that string directly. You’d have to return a `HttpResponse`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817007/django-return-string-from-view) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

There should be some method of actually adding the HOST URL and bringing it into the editor.